# SKLearn feature extraction - Loading features from dicts

Tags: scikit-learn

I have the following dataset which I would like to Vectorize so that I can do machine learning on.

Dataset:

```
amtlist = [
{'AMOUNT': 9000100}, {'AMOUNT': 9001000}, {'AMOUNT': 9002135.18}
]
```

Code:

```
from sklearn.feature_extraction import DictVectorizer
vec = DictVectorizer
vec.fit_transform(amtlist).toarray()
```

I am getting the following error:

```
TypeError: fit_transform() missing 1 required positional argument: 'X'
```

How can I fix this so that I can get the desired result? i.e.:

```
array([[9000100, 9001000, 9002135.18]])
```

Answer (score 0):

I was missing the parenthesis ()

```
vec = DictVectorizer()
```